# View [_forms] not found. in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

**routes.php**

```
Route::get('/course/{course_id}/classes/create', array('as' => 'account.profile.courses.classes.create', 'uses' => 'AccountController@createCourseClass'));
```

**controller**

```
public function createCourseClass($course_id)
{
    $course = Course::findOrFail($course_id);
    $studios = Studio::all();
    return View::make('account.profile.courses.addClass',compact('course','studios'));
}
```

**addClass.blade.php**

```
{{ Form::open(array('route' => 'account.profile.courses.classes.create')) }}
    @include('_forms')
{{ Form::close() }}
```

Can Anyone help me that how to include _form inside addClass.blade.php.

Comment: I have done little bit mistake. Sorry this question is closed.
@include('account.profile.courses._forms')

Comment: Please delete the question yourself.